# Read XML file which is on the same path level as XSD file

Tags: xml, maven, xsd

I would like to read my XML and XSD file which are on the same path level as my packages are:

It looks the following way:

```
first level: pom.xml, xml and xsd file
other level: many packages, like: com.something.else\com\something
                                  com.something.different\com\different
```

I already have the code to use both files but I do not know which path I have to use?

This is my code which works but only with a full path and this is not what I want to have:
    File xmlFile = new File("C:\somewhere\");
    private static String XSDresourceStream = "com\something";

```
try {
    if (xmlFile.exists()) {
        SchemaFactory sf = 
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(loadXSD());
...
private static Source loadXSD() {
    Source xsd = new StreamSource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(XSDresourceStream));
return xsd;
}
```

Later on it will be built with Maven.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/ - I hope this link will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Resources that you want to end up at the root of your JAR should go into `src/main/resources`. Unless you redefined your resource directories, of course. Also see the standard Maven project [directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the links you suggested me!